# awk cut from specific word in string

Tags: awk

I have those strings

```
gcc-4.8.3-1.aix7.1.ppc.rpm
gcc-c++-4.8.3-1.aix7.1.ppc.rpm
gcc-cpp-4.8.3-1.aix7.1.ppc.rpm
gcc-gfortran-4.8.3-1.aix7.1.ppc.rpm
libgcc-4.8.3-1.aix7.1.ppc.rpm
```

I want to cut starting from ".aix7.1" to end
to obtain

```
gcc-4.8.3-1
gcc-c++-4.8.3-1
gcc-gfortran-4.8.3-1
libgcc-4.8.3-1
```

Plese,how to do this with awk?

Comment: I know a solution with sed,simply using s:4.3 etc etc::g,but i want to know awk

Comment: `awk -F'.aix7.1' '{print $1}'` But there is more appropriate solutons with `sed` and `bash variables`

Comment: @Costas, please post that as an answer

Comment: @Costas; the two dots (`.`) in the field separator should better be escaped `\\.` since the `FS` is a regexp.

Comment: @Janis `aix7` is just enough to sure indicate where to separate the line, so for simplity OP can leave `.` as is (even if it can be treat as `any symbol`)

Comment: @Costas; while this is true for those few specific strings in the question, it's not appropriate for a general solution. Mind that files like, say, "libaix701.hp-ux.ppc.rpm" would lead to wrong results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
root@localhost:~# cat test
gcc-4.8.3-1.aix7.1.ppc.rpm
gcc-c++-4.8.3-1.aix7.1.ppc.rpm
gcc-cpp-4.8.3-1.aix7.1.ppc.rpm
gcc-gfortran-4.8.3-1.aix7.1.ppc.rpm
libgcc-4.8.3-1.aix7.1.ppc.rpm
root@localhost:~# awk 'BEGIN{FS=".aix7.1"} {print $1}' test
gcc-4.8.3-1
gcc-c++-4.8.3-1
gcc-cpp-4.8.3-1
gcc-gfortran-4.8.3-1
libgcc-4.8.3-1
root@localhost:~#
```

Answer (score 5):

I would split the line on dots and remove the last 4 fields

```
awk -F. -v OFS=. '{NF-=4}1'
```

But Costas's code in his comment more directly answers the requirements.

Comment: tricky and nice!